# Help with workflow rule criteria

Tags: workflow, datetime

I need to include a date field in my workflow rule criteria.

The field "registerDate__c" is of type DATETIME.

My criteria should express that the registerDate__c is longer than 30 days ago.

I wrote:

```
Now() - registerDate__c > 30
```

Obviously this is incorrect, because the result of this equation is probably not in days?.

My whole workflow criteria is:

```
A_Stage__c == 'Applicant' && 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Lost')) && 
Now() - Qual__r.registerDate__c > 30
```

When this criteria evaluates to true, I will update a field. 
Usually, when working with date fields in a workflow, I would use a time-based workflow, but in this case, my date field is in a related object, so I am not sure which way would be the best to do it.

tia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DATEVALUE() function to first cast NOW to a Date type rather than a Datetime type.  Then you your subtraction logic should work.  As an example:

```
A_Stage__c == 'Applicant' && 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Lost')) && 
DATEVALUE(Now()) - Qual__r.registerDate__c > 30
```

More on the DATEVALUE function here: https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&siteLang=en_US#DATEVALUE